# Included layout keeps collapsing in coordinator layout

Tags: xml, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a coordinatorlayout that have some included layouts, everytime I go to the visual designer to edit all included layouts are collapsed to 48dp. They aren't collapsed when i'm editing in the text tab. Was wondering if anyone found a workaround? All my included layouts have a recyclerview if that helps anything, since they seem to have been troublesome inside the coordinatorlayout before.